# FullAuditedEntity, ObjectMapper: CreatorUserId Null when Creating New Entry or Deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, objectmapper, object-object-mapping, asp.net-boilerplate

I have been posting data to a **Full Audited Entity** via the API. As it is `FullAuditedEntity`, it should automatically be created with creatorId, creationTime and a couple other column values. But when I checked in the database, **`CreatorUserID` is `null`** even though `CreationTime` is there. It **should be `1` cos I posted with the default admin**. Furthermore, when I delete the rows, the same happens: I can only see `DeletionTime` but not `DeleterUserId`.

Below is the data captured by the API Endpoints that I can see using breakpoints:

[image]

I experimented with **two Object Mapping Methods** creating `output` and `output2` but **both of them gives the same `null` value** for `CreatorUserId`. By right, both `CreatorUserId` and `CreationTime` should have values by this stage.

```
        [AbpAuthorize]
        public async Task<Rule> CreateAsync(CreateRuleInput input)
        {
            Rule output = Mapper.Map<CreateRuleInput, Rule>(input);
            Rule output2 = ObjectMapper.Map< Rule>(input);
            return await _ruleManager.Create(output);
        }
```

Is there anything wrong with my object mapping functions?

Comment: Is `TenantId` in database?

Comment: @aaron Yes, it is. I have to put it manually in the JSON post object, and it shows in the database.

Comment: Can you check `AbpSession.UserId` and `AbpSession.TenantId`?

Comment: @aaron where do i have to check those?

Comment: Is that method in an AppService?

Comment: @aaron Yes, the methods are in xxxAppService.cs

Comment: Then you can do `var abpSession = AbpSession` and set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the default Admin because it has no tenant.

From **another tenant, I created a new user** and post data using the new user's credentials. Then I post the data by **leaving out `tenantId` in the post body**. And it works just fine.

I used to specify `tenantId` in the post data object for the **default Admin** (Host tenant). If I **don't specify `tenantId` or put `0`, it gives `Server Internal Error: 500`**. So, I have to **specify `tenantId` in the post body object**. I think because of that it somehow messes with the mappings inside the API because **default Admin has no tenant**.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your object mapping functions.

> I experimented with two Object Mapping Methods... By right, both CreatorUserId and CreationTime should have values by this stage.

`CreatorUserId` and `CreationTime` only have values after `SaveChanges()` is called.

> I have to put [TenantId] manually in the JSON post object, and it shows in the database.

You should not do that. `CreatorUserId` is [only set if the entity belongs to the current tenant](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/2f79821b3c09132394ec01f1673b7fad8e6893af/src/Abp/Domain/Entities/Auditing/EntityAuditingHelper.cs#L50-L55).

> I can see UserId which is 1 in breakpoint. Somehow it gets ignored during mapping.

The proper way to create an entity as "Default" tenant admin, is to log in as the tenant admin.

`UserId = 1` means you are logged in as host admin. "Default" tenant admin has `UserId = 2`.

> If I don't specify tenantId or put 0, it gives Server Internal Error: 500.

If you want host to create `Rule`, make sure it implements `IMayHaveTenant` not `IMustHaveTenant`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In fact, i just found out about it and posted the answer just now. I don't know if it's a feature or a bug but the default host admin should also be able to create entity. Cos right now, it's caused a lot of confusions in me

Comment: If you want host to create `Rule`, make sure it implements `IMayHaveTenant` not `IMustHaveTenant`.